# Stone-Čech compactification of partial semigroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology

Recently, I have read about partial semigroup, where binary composition of two elements isn't guaranteed always. I read it in Hindman Strauss's book from where i get the idea of weak ring and already discussed my confusion here. In this book, there is not any guarantee whether the Stone-Čech compactification of a partial semigroup is a semigroup. Thus they have taken a subsemigroup of it and proved various results. My question is, if $(S,+)$ is a commutative partial semigroup then is $(\beta S,+)$ a partial semigroup or not? Where $+$ on $\beta S$ induced from $+$ on $S$.

Answer (score 1):

I think ($\beta {S}$,.) is partial semigroup, atleast if S is commutative, defined as,
p.q is defined if p,q both in $\delta {S}$ or at least one of them is in $\delta {S}$ and it is undefined otherwise, i.e. if both are not in $\delta {S}$. 
Now for,
p $\cdot$ (q $\cdot$ r)=(p $\cdot$ q)$\cdot$r.
If in one side is defined for suppose the left one, the otherside should be defined.
You can check this associativity relation of partial semigroup by the condition given at first.